# How to embed a scoped html (css) in a document

Tags: html, css

I need to be able to embed HTML snippets (nested elements and CSS) fetched from a remote api inside my document, in a way that their CSS won't affect on my whole document.

I need to fetch (random) gmail messages HTMLs and embed them in my website. The thing is that most messages have their CSS tags to style the message html. The problem is that some of these CSS mess up with my own document CSS. How can I embed an html snippet with CSS, in a way that it will have its own scope and not interact with what's outside of it?

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Your gmail messages</h1>
<div id="gmail-message">
  <!-- Here to be injected automatically. Changing classes, etc is not possible -->
  <h1>This a gmail message</h1>
  <style type="text/css">
  h1 {
  color: red;
  }
  </style>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The h1 tag outside the gmail-message div is also affected and is therefore red.
What do I need to do to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found my solution.

First, insert an empty iframe tag somewhere.

```
<iframe id="iframeTag" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```

Second, load the html snippet into that iframe, the following way:

```
var doc = document.getElementById('iframeTag').contentWindow.document;
doc.open();
doc.write(<html_snippet>);
doc.close();
```

This way the `<html_snippet>`'s css won't mix up with the outer document's.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use an iframe.

Another solution would be to extract all css and html, then add an attribute (example: scope) to every html tag inside of gmail-messag. 
Then modifiy the css and add an attribut selector.

Example:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Your gmail messages</h1>
<div id="gmail-message">
  <!-- Here to be injected automatically. Changing classes, etc is not possible -->
  <h1 scoped>This a gmail message</h1>
  <style type="text/css">
  h1[scoped] {
  color: red;
  }
  </style>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But propably using an ifram is a more easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use iframe / object / embed tag (tested on firefox). 
If you can use Javascript and HTML5 you can also use shadow DOM or make custom element that uses slot tag (also in shadowRoot).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into using [The Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM)

> An important aspect of web components is encapsulation — being **able to
>   keep the markup structure, style, and behavior hidden and separate
>   from other code on the page so that different parts do not clash**, and
>   the code can be kept nice and clean. The Shadow DOM API is a key part
>   of this, providing a way to attach a hidden separated DOM to an
>   element.

However, be aware this is new tech and, as always, Microsoft browsers don't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `srcdoc` attribute on `iframe` to scope your HTML and CSS.

```html
<iframe srcdoc="<p>Hello world!</p>"></iframe>
```

It's supported on all major browsers: https://caniuse.com/iframe-srcdoc