# How to insert a HTML Page inside HTML File without conflicting styles of each other

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have an HTML stored in database. I want to add that HTML page inside a HTML. the page has inline styling cdn of bootstrap etc. If I just add it inside a div element it affects the styling of the page that's it added to.

How can I insert the html page in the html without conflicting styles of each other?

Comment: `iframe` is your friend => https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Comment: Use iframe as solution check this answer maybe give a idea how to solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53987873/how-to-embed-a-scoped-html-css-in-a-document

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for your HTML and CSS:
HTML:

```
<div class="iframe-container"> <!--you can nest this inside a bootstrap grid-->
      <iframe id="my-Iframe" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.iframe-container{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; 
    height: 0;
}
.iframe-container iframe{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The JS is pretty interesting, Using the contentWindow property you can set it without needing to write to any file,

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("my-Iframe");
iframe.contentWindow.document = x; //x stands for the code that you want to 
put
```

Further Readings: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp